# How to pass array with single element from nest.js dto?

Tags: arrays, nestjs, dto

When passing array with single value nest.js dto, am not getting the value as an array.

Below is the dto code:

```js
export class DownloadDocsDto {
  @Transform(({ value }) => (Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value]))
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsArray()
  @IsString({ each: true })
  @ApiProperty({
    example: ['test.pdf'],
    description: 'Document Url List',
    required: true,
  })
  public urlList: [];
}
```

Below is the controller code:

```js
@Get('/download/docs')
@ApiOperation({ summary: 'Download documents' })
async downloadDocs(@Query() urlList: DownloadDocsDto) {
  console.log(urlList)
}
```

Am getting the Result:

```json
{ urlList: 'test.pdf' }
```

But I need the result as:

```json
{ urlList: ['test.pdf'] }
```

**When I pass more than one value in the dto, am getting the expected result.**

Need some valuable help.